# How to print a list with size 2 in an excel sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, list, numpy, openpyxl

I have created a list with size 2 in python and I want to print it in an excel sheet using openpyxl. I need to clarify here, that I want to print every line of the list as it is in excel, meaning two numbers separated with comma. Until now I haven't achieved to print the list in excel since I get " **raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))**" error. In the following code is the list that I want to print and the table as it should be in excel.

```
import numpy as np

line_grid=np.arange(2,7,2)
two=np.arange(1,7,2)
xy=np.vstack((two,line_grid)).T
df=np.ndarray.tolist(xy)
```

**Desired Table in excel**

[image: Desired Table in excel]

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

def save(file, name):
df = DataFrame(file)
df.transpose()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("rsc/" + name + ".xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="name", header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

..to save a numpy array as an excel file.

Comment: Hi Marcel, thank you for your answer but I want to print the two columns in one cell in excel separated with comma. Your solution prints the values in two separate columns

Comment: Oh sorry, I have read over this part in your answer. Maybe this link is helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456495/python-excel-automation-text-from-2-cells-into-1-cell